# Evitar que el indentar corte las líneas

Tags: php, html, vscode, extensiones

Trabajo con un monitor grande y quiero ver las líneas completas o cortarlas a mi antojo. La siguiente línea es como me gustaría que quedara

```
<input type="number" id="crn" name="crn_per" class="algo" readonly value="0">
```

Pero al indentar con `shift` + `alt` + `f` queda así

```
<input type="number" id="crn" name="crn_per"
    class="algo" readonly 
    value="0">
```

He probado varias extensiones (Format HTML in PHP, indent-rainbow, Prettier - Code formatter). Hace un tiempo estaba bien, sin cortar las líneas, no sé en cual actualización cambio y me esta "dañando" el código que estaba bien.

La pregunta es: ¿existe el parámetro para ajustar el largo de la línea?

Comment: Mencionas que probaste prettier... probaste a *configurarlo*??? Por defecto la mayoría de extensiones limita el código a tamaños mucho menores que lo que cabe en una pantalla de tamaño más bien pequeño (17" por ejemplo). Esto es porque el código no suele empezar siempre en el margen izquierdo, si no que tiene indentaciones..., tenemos paneles laterales, etc, de ahí que suelan limitar a alrededor de 80 caracteres. Quieres más?? Configúralo!! Normalmente todas las extensiones son configurables. Para eso está la [**documentación**](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html)